# using await inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript

I want to use await inside of an ajax call like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../../../preload.php',
  data: { id: "testdata", directories: directories },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: async function(result) {
    if (preloadFirstTime === false) {
      return;
    };
    await foo(); // This is await function I want to use
    preload(getResults(result));
    updateSourceFolders(result);
    preloadFirstTime = false;
  },
});
```

Since this is the first time I want to use await inside the ajax I wonder this is possible or it may generate any errors in some situations?

the PHP inside just generates a list of files inside `directories` folder in the server.

Comment: You don't need to use `$.ajax` - you should use `fetch` directly, which uses native `Promise` objects. `$.ajax` is from jQuery and is almost 15 years old now.

Comment: What is `foo`? Why aren't you using [promise with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326160/3082296) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

Comment: I want to proceed to `preload(getResults(result));` only after `foo` is resolved.

Comment: That's the only thing I need.

Comment: What does `foo` do?

Comment: it will resolve when `canplaythrough` event for a audio is fired. I want to proceed to next lines after `foo` when I can play an specific audio.

Comment: use `foo().then(res => {preload(getResults(result));})`

Comment: You should be fine using async with jQuery Ajax, but you will want to use its thenable, not the success callback.  This will then allow you to chain the promises etc.

Comment: What exactly is the *problem*? If this is about working code, your question is better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)